# Is Increment Thread safe?

Tags: mysql, grails

I'm implementing a sequence generator for my database, via Grails. I've defined my domain class, and I want to specify a sequence. At present, I'm using:

```
static mapping = {
    id generator: 'uuid'
    version false
}
```

But this is generating long, 128 bit IDs, which I'm conscious that the user might have a hard time using. To combat this, I decided that it might be better to use normal, incrementing IDs, so I found [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator) resource, informing me about the various options I had for preconfigured sequence generators.

I had a look at `increment`, and found this description:

> increment - 
>   generates identifiers of type long, short or int that are unique only when no other process is inserting data into the same table. Do not use in a cluster.

I have one Grails application inserting data, but several users may be inputting data at the same time. As I understand it, Grails (like a normal Servlet) will assign a new thread to each request made from the user. Does this mean then, that `increment` is not a good fit, because even though there is only one application, there will be multiple threads attempting to insert?

If `increment` is not a good fit, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If increment is not a good fit, what other options do I have?

As IsidroGHIf stated in the comment if you don't specify id generator GORM will by default choose the native strategy to generate ids, which in case of MySQL are auto-incrementing columns.

They are definitely thread-safe, they also work in a cluster (compared to increment) and they will by default start with 1, incrementing also by 1 so it won't be long 128 bit IDs.

Comment: This is what we worked out in the end. I'll mark this as correct. Nice!

Answer (score -2):

All threads running in a single instance application are executed in the same process so using `increment` is thread safe.
In this case, the Hibernate session associated to the process (associated to a thread running in the process) manages these IDs and assures uniqueness.

Anyway, the `increment` mode is normally (at least in my case) used for testing and/or early stage development phases.

If your database supports sequences, I'd probably use the sequence mode.

Comment: The `MySQL` DBMS does not support sequences, which is why I'm resorting to the predefined one supplied by hibernate/grails.

Comment: If you don't define a generator, the default (``autoincrement`` for MySQL) would be used.

Comment: IMHO this answer is fundamentally wrong. "executed in the same process so using increment is thread safe" - this is nonsense in it's nutshell. "Hibernate session associated to the process" - Hibernate session is not bound to the process it's bound to the current request thread. It is opened on the beginning of the request and closed after request is processed.

Comment: So can you provide an answer of your own @lukelazarovic ?

Comment: @christopher I would like to, but I don't know it either:) I suppose somehow hibernate has to take care of it, but I don't know how.

Comment: @lukelazarovic and all the threads are executed in the same process, so saying the session is associated to the process is correct. That is what I wanted to mean.

Comment: @christopher Although IsidiroGH explanation is wrong he is right about using of sequences - if your database supports them, they are the natural choice. What database you use?

Comment: As I said at the top, I'm using the `MySQL` DBMS.